# How to get value from input field by clicking button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need help to correct my code. When I click on the Save button to retrieve data from each input field the HTML code is printed from my PHP loop, so I need to use `$this`, but I'm not able to adjust the code.

I don't know why, but if i set `div#edit_list` on click event, the entire code works fine, but not if I click the Save button.

```html
<div id="edit_fields" class="glass">
  <div id="data_holder">
    <p>Nome:</p><input type="text" id="ed_name" name="ed_name" value="<?= $name_dex ?>" />
  </div>
  <div id="data_holder">
    <p>Link:</p><input type="text" id="ed_link" name="ed_link" value="<?= $link_dex ?>" />
  </div>
  <div id="data_holder">
    <p>Tipo:</p><input type="text" id="ed_type" name="ed_type" value="<?= $type_dex ?>" readonly />
  </div>
  <div id="data_holder">
    <p>Shiny:</p><label id="cb_holder"><input type="checkbox" id="ed_shy" name="ed_shy" value="s" <?= $ckd; ?> /><span id="checkmark"></span></label>
  </div>
  <div id="data_holder">
    <input id="submit" class="btn1" type="submit" name="save" value="Salva" />
  </div>
  <div id="nr_dex">#
    <?= $px_dex ?>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="ed_alola" name="ed_alola" value="<?= $alola ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" id="ed_alo_type" name="ed_alo_type" value="<?= $alo_type ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" id="row" name="row" value="<?= $key ?>" />
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#submit", this).click(function() {
    var j_name = $("#ed_name", this).val();
    var j_link = $("#ed_link", this).val();
    var j_type = $("#ed_type", this).val();

    if ($("#ed_shy").is(":checked")) {
      var cb_shy = $("#ed_shy").val();
    } else {
      var cb_shy = "";
    }

    var j_alola = $("#ed_alola", this).val();
    var j_alo_type = $("#ed_alo_type", this).val();
    var index = $("#row", this).val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        save: '',
        ed_name: j_name,
        ed_link: j_link,
        ed_type: j_type,
        ed_shy: cb_shy,
        ed_alola: j_alola,
        ed_alo_type: j_alo_type,
        row: index
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(edit) {
        alert(edit);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Here a non working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/04w3fdch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `, this` in all your `$("#...")` calls. In the `click` event handler, `this` is the submit button, but the input fields are not contained within the button.

You need to replace that with the DIV that contains all the inputs. Also, IDs should be unique, so you should be using classes rather than IDs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.submit").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest(".edit_fields");
    var j_name = $(".ed_name", row).val();
    var j_link = $(".ed_link", row).val();
    var j_type = $(".ed_type", row).val();

    if ($(".ed_shy").is(":checked")) {
      var cb_shy = $(".ed_shy").val();
    } else {
      var cb_shy = "";
    }
    alert("Nome = " + j_name);
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0
}

.edit_fields {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit_fields" class="glass">
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Nome:</p><input type="text" class="ed_name" name="ed_name" value="Name..." />
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Link:</p><input type="text" class="ed_link" name="ed_link" value="a link..." />
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Tipo:</p><input type="text" class="ed_type" name="ed_type" value="type..." readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Shiny:</p><label class="cb_holder"><input type="checkbox" class="ed_shy" name="ed_shy" value="s" /><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <input class="submit" class="btn1" type="submit" name="save" value="Salva" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="edit_fields" class="glass">
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Nome:</p><input type="text" class="ed_name" name="ed_name" value="another Name..." />
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Link:</p><input type="text" class="ed_link" name="ed_link" value="another link..." />
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Tipo:</p><input type="text" class="ed_type" name="ed_type" value="another type..." readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Shiny:</p><label class="cb_holder"><input type="checkbox" class="ed_shy" name="ed_shy" value="s" /><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <input class="submit" class="btn1" type="submit" name="save" value="Salva" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="edit_fields" class="glass">
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Nome:</p><input type="text" class="ed_name" name="ed_name" value="Third Name..." />
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Link:</p><input type="text" class="ed_link" name="ed_link" value="Third link..." />
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Tipo:</p><input type="text" class="ed_type" name="ed_type" value="Third type..." readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <p>Shiny:</p><label class="cb_holder"><input type="checkbox" class="ed_shy" name="ed_shy" value="s" /><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="data_holder">
    <input class="submit" class="btn1" type="submit" name="save" value="Salva" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works only for the first element, because i'm under foreach loop php, so i have many others DIV...here is the why i need to use $this...

Comment: You can't use the same ID in every DIV, you should be using classes.

Comment: Its the same... look this fiddle and try to make it working: https://jsfiddle.net/04w3fdch/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the inputs were in their own DIVs. Need to use `.closest(".edit_fields")`

Comment: Please, let me know where i have to insert that

Comment: you say so? `var row = $(this).closest(".edit_fields");`

Comment: That's the fix I made.

Comment: Ok... look the fiddle edited: https://jsfiddle.net/dba8ehcn/1/
Still nothing worked... :(

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't do anything with any of the variables, how can you tell whether it's working?

Comment: That's why I added the alert in my version.

Comment: Finally it works! Nevermind use class or id, you can see that work even with ID: https://jsfiddle.net/dba8ehcn/2/
The missing key was `var row = $(this).closest(".edit_fields");`

Comment: You shouldn't depend on it. Duplicate IDs are not really supported.